# Where to incorrporate IF and Else if file doesnt exist after os.walk?

Tags: python

Ignore the arcpy. I know some of this deals with python for ArcGIS, but my question and problem is python related. How would you skip the arcpy.Merge and arcpy.Clip if 'AAA010.shp' does not exist in the directory that os.walk is going through. Currently, the If and Else causes the script to skip over the .merge and .clip even though the 'AAA010.shp' does exist.

```
import os, fnmatch, arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace  =  r’C:\Users\sysadmin\desktop\datamanagement\MGCP.gdb’

fcMerged = ‘MergedFeatureClass’

fcClipped = ‘ClippedFeatureClass’

fcToClip = r’C:\Users\sysadmin\desktop\datamanagement\Country.shp’

filesMatched = list()

for root, subfolders, files in os.walk(r’C:\Users\sysadmin\desktop\datamanagement\MGCP_Raw’):

  for f in fnmatch.filer(files, ‘AAA010.shp’):
    filesMatched.append(os.path.join(root,f))

if 'AAA010.shp' in filesMatched:

   arcpy.Merge_management (filesMatched, fcMerged)

   arcpy.Clip_analysis (fcMerged, fcToClip, Extraction_Mine)

else: pass
```